# comparator with capture

Tags: c++, comparator

I want to create a `boost::binomial_heap` with a comparator that uses external data, something like

```
bool compare(int a1, int a2) 
{
  return price[a1] < price[a2];
}
```

(here `price`, for example, is a `vector` of doubles.)

How to declare the compare function that captures `price`?

Comment: What exactly is `price`?

Comment: For example a vector of doubles indexable by int defined in the same class in which the heap is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C++11 code shows how to do so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
int main()
{   
    std::vector<double> price{0.3, 0.2, 0.1};
    auto cmp = [&price](int i, int j){return price[i] < price[j];};
    std::map<int, float, decltype(cmp)> m(cmp);
    m[2] = 'b';
    m[1] = 'c';
}
```

The line

```
    std::vector<double> price{0.3, 0.2, 0.1};
```

defines the vector `price`.

The line

```
    auto cmp = [&price](int i, int j){return price[i] < price[j];};
```

creates a lambda function that captures `price` by reference.

The line

```
    std::map<int, float, decltype(cmp)> m(cmp);
```

creates a container (in this case `std::map`) parameterized by this type, and taking an object as the comparator. Using this with a different container will be similar.

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to create a class that contains both the map 'm' and the vector 'price' as members? Is it possible to declare a function 'cmp' that captures 'this' and then use its type in the declaration of a member variable 'm'?

Comment: @danatel Yes, that's the way to do so.